# How to generate Random 26 length character string with no duplicates(characters) in c#?

Tags: c#, string

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
        string[] coupon = new string[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < coupon.Length; i++)
        {
            coupon[i] = GenerateCoupon(26, rnd);
        }
        textBox1 .Text=(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, coupon));
```

***** Function***********\

```
  public static string GenerateCoupon(int length, Random random)
    {
        string characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
        {
            result.Append(characters[random.Next(characters.Length)]);

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

**Strings that code generates :**

kheeuasampxqxmoohcrufznugp

vrlncvbftinynhdufjdikacjsi

vblltkxeeapymbprtgaiojqkte

qyfvpcvtazuiodbidcfgwcssgw

ijtlkbrpuyzilndsaqxlrxhggo

emhngmostlapotqziciursddcc

vvflcnewwehgsntstrskbduroe

**But i need a code that generates the string that have 26 character length and no duplicate character :**

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba

mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq

qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujmikolp

bhuijnmkoplqazxswedcvfrtgb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), or simply

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var newstr = String.Concat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
```

Comment: Just a FYI to be careful about. Doing a OrderBy on a value that changes technically breaks the contract expected by OrderBy. In the current version of .NET all that happens is it could take extra long for the sorting to happen, but that does not mean in the future it could [make demons fly out of your noise](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) (or more likely, throw an exception or have enteries duplicated/lost)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain So you could give a better solution?

Comment: @RageCompex EZI already mentioned the better solution, a Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some [shuffle algorithms](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) and apply it to your character set.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a string of `a-z`. For example: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".

After that, randomly shuffle the string based on the index of each letter.